# redirect to different url on manual refresh with angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to have a url redirect to a different url only when i click on reload on the browser. However, right now every time it lands on that page, it automatically redirects right away.

Basically when iam on www.mypage/abcde ; if i click on reload on the browser i want to be able to go routed to www.mypage, but only if i manually refresh, not automatically, because this prevents from displaying the content of "/abcde" since it happens right away.
Any idea?

```
 app.run(["$rootScope", "$location", "$state",
    function ($rootScope, $location, $state) {

        $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            if ($location.path() == "/abcde" && performance.navigation.type == 1) {

                var  Location = next.split("/abcde")[0]
                window.location.href =  Location

            }

        });
    }
])
```

Comment: Your wording is very confusing. Can you try to rephrase your question to make it more clear?

Comment: @Tyler ok done.

Comment: So to clarify, when you navigate to /abcde from within your app you would like the normal the behavior but if you refresh the page while on /abcde you would like it to take you to www.mypage.com?

Comment: yes thats right

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully [PerformanceNavigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation) will be useful.

It comes with three values 0,1,2 for example

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    // reloaded
  }
```

You can use this condition to design the route